# Query to count unique sample IDs with number of tests passed/failed

Tags: database, join, count, distinct

I have a linked database and have created a report that summarizes samples tested between a specified date range: product, product group, product description, test description - how many passed/failed that test. All works well except I need to tally the number of samples tested per product group not the number of tests – which is what is currently outputting. I have a query that analyzes the results and allocates a pass/fail designation and these are counted; I've also created a query that counts the number of samples submitted (also between a date range) but can't figure out how to incorporate that into the main query used for the report. The sum function adds up the number of tests but I need the number of samples (i.e. one sample could have 5 different tests and may only pass 2 of them). I am having difficulty trying to put 2 + 2 together! [I've attached an image of my report design to help visualize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqMCo.png)

**Copy of LabResultsAnalysisCountPass-Fail Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].Name, [Copy of    LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].Plant, [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].ProductGroup, [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].ProductDescription, [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].TestDescription, [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].Pass, Count([Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].Pass) AS CountOfPass
FROM [Copy of Count Lab Samples Query], LabProductTest INNER JOIN [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query] ON LabProductTest.LabProductTestID = [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].LabProductTestID
GROUP BY [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].Name, [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].Plant, [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].ProductGroup, [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].ProductDescription, [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].TestDescription, [Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query].Pass, LabProductTest.Deleted
HAVING (((LabProductTest.Deleted)=False));
```

**Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query:**

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Lab Results start date] DateTime;
SELECT PlantInformation.Name, LabPlantSample.Plant, Product.ProductDescription, ProductGroup.ProductGroupCode, ProductGroup.ProductGroup, LabTestProvincialStandard.TestDescription, LabTestProvincialStandard.Standard,                IIf([ResultTxt]="NEGATIVE","Passed",IIf([ResultTxt]="POSITIVE","Failed",IIf([Standard]="NEGATIVE" And [ResultTxt]<>"NEGATIVE" And [ResultPrefix]<>"<","Failed",IIf([Standard]="NEGATIVE" And (IsNumeric([ResultTxt])<="10" And [ResultPrefix]="<"),"Passed",IIf(CCur([ResultTxt])<=(CCur([Standard])) And (IsNull([ResultPrefix]) Or [ResultPrefix]="<" Or [ResultPrefix]=""),"Passed",IIf(IsNumeric([ResultTxt])<=10 And [ResultPrefix]="<","Passed",IIf(IsNumeric([ResultTxt])>(IsNumeric([Standard])) And (IsNull([ResultPrefix]) Or [ResultPrefix]="<" Or [ResultPrefix]=""),"Failed",IIf(CCur([ResultTxt])>(CCur([Standard])) And (IsNull([ResultPrefix]) Or [ResultPrefix]=">"),"Failed","Failed")))))))) AS Pass, LabProductSample.LabProductSampleID, LabProductTest.LabProductTestID, LabPlantSample.SampleDate
FROM PlantInformation INNER JOIN (LabPlantSample INNER JOIN (((LabTestProvincialStandard INNER JOIN (Product INNER JOIN ProductGroup ON Product.ProductGroupCode = ProductGroup.ProductGroupCode) ON LabTestProvincialStandard.ProductGroupCode = ProductGroup.ProductGroupCode)     INNER JOIN LabProductTest ON LabTestProvincialStandard.TestDescription = LabProductTest.TestDescription) INNER JOIN LabProductSample ON (LabProductSample.LabProductSampleID = LabProductTest.LabProductSampleID) AND (Product.ProductDescription = LabProductSample.ProductDescription)) ON LabPlantSample.PlantSampleID = LabProductSample.PlantSampleID) ON PlantInformation.Plant = LabPlantSample.Plant
WHERE (((LabPlantSample.SampleDate)>=[Enter Lab Results start date]) AND ((LabProductTest.Deleted)=False) AND ((LabProductSample.Deleted)=False) AND ((LabPlantSample.Deleted)=False) AND ((PlantInformation.Inactive)=False))
ORDER BY PlantInformation.Name, ProductGroup.ProductGroupCode, ProductGroup.ProductGroup, LabTestProvincialStandard.TestDescription;
```

**Copy of Count Lab Samples Query:**

```
PARAMETERS [Enter Lab Results start date] DateTime, [Enter Lab Results end date] DateTime;
SELECT PlantInformation.Plant, PlantInformation.Name, Count(LabProductSample.LabProductSampleID) AS CountOfLabProductSampleID, LabPlantSample.SampleDate
FROM PlantInformation INNER JOIN (LabPlantSample INNER JOIN LabProductSample ON LabPlantSample.PlantSampleID = LabProductSample.PlantSampleID) ON PlantInformation.Plant = LabPlantSample.Plant
GROUP BY PlantInformation.Plant, PlantInformation.Name, LabPlantSample.SampleDate, LabProductSample.Deleted
HAVING (((LabPlantSample.SampleDate) Between [Enter Lab Results start date] And [Enter Lab Results end date]) AND ((LabProductSample.Deleted)=False));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest solution is to output the number of passed tests, the number of failed tests, and the number of samples as separate columns on the report.

If that is acceptable, you can add a count of passes and count fails to "Copy of LabResultsAnalysisWithPass Query" (and remove the existing "pass" column). Then in "Copy of LabResultsAnalysisCountPass-Fail", sum the passes, sum the fails and count "LabProductSampleID". You wouldn't need the last query at all.

Comment: Thank you Seamus for your quick response. I cannot remove the "Pass" column as it is interpreting the entered values of tests to either a 'pass' or 'fail' - hence the long IIf statement. I'm working with data that is entered in another program that we have limited abilities with; I designed the report to match that in the program but I may have to redesign it in order to get what the inspectors would like to see.